# Two variable in one block - liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

consider these variables in `liquid` in `jeyll`:

```
url: ex.com
baseurl: /blog
```

Now I want address `ex.com/blog` with `liquid` 
in one block like this:

```
{{url,baseurl}}
```

But it not permitted. How I can do this?
I do this in this way now:

```
{{url}}{{baseurl}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` good for this.

```
{{url | append: baseurl}}
```